# Which Steelseries headsets have the crossfader?

Tags: gaming, headphones, headset

I LOVED the original Steelseries Arctis 7; I'm talking the very first one that came out several years ago. The audio crossfader between chat and game sound was the greatest feature I never realized I needed. Since that headset went bad, I've gone through two more: The Arctis 7P and 7P+, and I was shocked to learn that the crossfader had been removed on both of these models in favor of this stupid sidetone adjuster. That dial broke on my current headset and now I'm forced to listen to myself and keyboard/mouse amplified 10x louder than it even is.

Looking through all the different headsets Steelseries has now, I can't find any of them that explicitly say they have that crossfader, and the original Arctis 7 is now $250. Do ANY of their current models have the crossfader or has that been completely removed now?